# Java - Listeners detect the socket as closed

Tags: java, sockets, imap, listeners

I'm coding an app in Java + IMAP protocol to read GMail messages and so on.
I've built an interface with JPane and everything works fine except for the socket when I try to use it inside listeners. For example:

```
btnRemove.addActionListener (new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                BufferedReader br = mail.getBr();
                PrintWriter pw = mail.getPw();
                pw.println(". STATUS INBOX (unseen)");
                pw.flush();

                try 
                {
                    System.out.println(br.readLine());

                    while(br.ready())
                    {
                        System.out.println(br.readLine());
                    }
                } 
                catch (IOException e1) 
                {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

This gives: java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed

Same for my JList listener.

If I use the buffer code out of the listener, it works perfectly. What's the problem?

Comment: Why don't you use the [Java Mail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html)?

Comment: Are you closing the mail socket elsewhere in your code?

Comment: I cannot use any other than IMAP. Class work requeriments.

Comment: @gknicker No. I'm not closing the socket anywhere.

Comment: The problem is that you closed the socket but didn't remove your listener.

Comment: @EJP I didn't close the socket. I can actually use the code related to socket (which is inside the listener) before our after the listener.

Comment: you're working with multi-threading ? Things can be weird.